# ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker

I have problem connecting windows docker to WSL 2 under ubuntu linux distros.

`ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375. Is the docker daemon running? errors pretty printing info`

Eventhough i have export the param to the environment path into this file(~/.bashrc) but it will still showing the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kfm2.png)

I have also enable TCP on my windows docker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6boRY.png)

I have also started the docker, but it will still showing the same error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RNwP.png)

Comment: Have you edited `/etc/daemon/docker.json` to tell it to listen on port 2375?

Comment: at linux distros? i have checked on my linux but I does not have this path on my linux

Comment: I don't know about WSL2, but on Linux it won't listen on localhost unless it's configured to. If you don't configure that it only listens on `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.